# Migrating from SVN to GIT with a particular file structure

Tags: git, svn

I have a project in subversion that I am trying to migrate to git. The project has the following file structure:

```
Project/main/tags
Project/main/trunk
```

What I am trying to do is port this project to Git, while keeping the history, but removing the "main" folder, so that the structure is:

Project/tags
Project/trunk

I have search but couldn't find something very specific.

Also, I have pushed to stash the wrong folder structure and I am trying to correct that. I guess

```
git init
```

might be sufficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is using only

```
--no-minimize-url
```

without any other tags.
Usually, other answers are filled with unneeded tags for this case.